# Ionic2 Disable 300ms delay on label element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

I'm displaying a custom view for my radiobuttons inside a form and toggle it with the label-for-attribute. Ionic2 itself removes the 300ms delay on anchors and buttons but i'm not shure how to remove it for the click on the label.

How can i remove this delay on the label-click or implement this in a different way so i can toggle the radio?

```
<input type="radio" id="{{input.key}}.{{i}}" name="{{input.key}}"
           (change)="radioSelectionChanged(subinput,input)"
           [checked]="subinput.selected">

<label *ngIf="!macroCodeProvider.isEqualType(input.type,configInputType.Select)"
           class=""
           for="{{input.key}}.{{i}}">
      {{subinput.label}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I only add this answer just in case if this could help some other SO users*. Like you can see in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/troubleshooting/#click-delays)

> [...], you may need to add a (click) event to an element that is not
>   normally clickable. When you do this you may experience a 300ms delay
>   from the time you click the element to the event firing. To remove
>   this delay, you can add the tappable attribute to your element.

```
 <div tappable (click)="doClick()">I am clickable!</div>
```

So by adding the `tappable` attribute (and the click event) to the target element, you can remove that 300ms delay.

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced the label with an button which on click called the following function:

```
  radioSelectionChanged(selectedInput: ConfiguratorRadioGroupInput, radioGroup: ConfiguratorRadioGroup) {
    radioGroup.inputs.map(input => {
      input.selected = (input.key == selectedInput.key);
    });
    console.log(selectedInput);
  }
```